# After adding a SSD to my MacBook, the HD never spins down

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, macbook-pro

I added a SSD to my MacBook Pro 17 as the primary drive attached to the SATA controller. I moved the HD to the optical bay using the OptiBay from MCE Technologies which I use for my home directory.

The problem I have encountered is the HD seems to never stop spinning.

I have modified the sleep settings, hoping one of the various options would solve my problem without success.

Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

For what it's worth, I have a MacBook 1,1 and tried the same configuration:  Intel x25 MLC SSD in HDD bay and 500GB WD Scorpio Blue in PATA-SATA optical bay caddy.  I tried many things to try and spin down the HDD (including the hdpam stuff) and never found success--though I honestly can't remember if I tried all of the remedies with my home directory on and off of the HDD.  It appears that WD Scorpio blues may not play nice with optical bay caddys and I was reluctant to live with extensive OS modifications since I've had to reload the OS so often during this experiment so I abandoned the configuration.  I have read that some other HDD brands work fine but I couldn't return the drive and was sick and tired of assembling/disassembling my MacBook--i've done it some many times now that i could probably do it in the dark.  Bottom line is that the WD Scorpio Blue/PATA-SATA optical caddy configuration does not appear to work properly with regard to spin down even after applying all of the remedies posted online.

With an SSD moved to the optical bay as the boot drive (SLC SSD this time borrowed from one of my other computers) and the HDD all warm and cozy in it's proper home I've found that the HD spins down properly with the "spin down disks when possible" option set in the Energy Saver Preferences panel--after 10 min by default, which I reduced to 1 min (see http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10346924-263.html).  I can report that HD often remains spun down for hours on end--I spend most of my time in the cloud.  HOWEVER, I now have a nagging sleep issue with occasional kernel panics when I close the lid even with hibernate mode off.  But this is an entirely different story...

Answer (score 1):

Using the HDD for your home directory is a recipe for power consumption. There's always processes like the Spotlight indexer (indexd) and others hitting it which will cause the disk to spin up.

What I do is have my OS install and home directory on my SSD, and have symlinks from directories like my iTunes Media folder to folders on the HDD. This allows the disk to spin down during regular use.

Comment: Great suggestion! A friend has done the same. I'll give it a shot and report my results.